# memory leak / badly written code or both - properly disposing of sqlconnection?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, web-applications, .net-1.1, sqlconnection

I am investigating an issue with a .net 1.1 web application where it seems that we had quite a few "Internal connection fatal error" exceptions possibly the connection objects staying open or not disposed of properly.  The web server eventually crashes under heavy load. I checked the code and we are in fact calling sqlconnection.close() in all places in the try catch finally

The project implements the following pattern. Can someone tell me if it looks like this may cause a memory leak?

The aspx webpage makes the following call in  Private Sub Page_Load

```
Dim oDictionary As New dbDictionary
tagVal = oDictionary.GetTag(41)
```

where dbDictionary is used for getting a sql table from DB

```
Public Class dbDictionary
    Inherits DBInteractionBase

Public Function GetTag(ByVal tagId)

       'uses the  _connection connection object and Executes sql which sometimes throws a sql exception, but closes the connection in finally

        GetDictConnectionString()

         'new sqlconnection object for another sqlcommand
        Dim dictConnection As New SqlConnection
        dictConnection = _connection  'At this point the _connection is closed.

        'I think the dictConnection is a reference to _connection

        Dim cmdToExecute As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand

        ' // Use base class' connection object
        cmdToExecute.Connection = dictConnection

        Try
            ' // Open connection.
            dictConnection.Open()

            ' // Execute query.
            adapter.Fill(toReturn)


        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Error occured.", ex)
        Finally
            ' // Close connection.
            dictConnection.Close()
            cmdToExecute.Dispose()
            adapter.Dispose()
        End Try


    End Function

    Private Function GetDictConnectionString()


        ' initialize SqlCommand... Use base class _connection object
        cmdToExecute.Connection = _connection

        Try
            _connection.Open()
            adapter.Fill(toReturn)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return "Error" ' Could this be the issue?  The original exception isn't released?
        Finally
            _connection.Close()
            cmdToExecute.Dispose()
            adapter.Dispose()
        End Try

End Class
```

Here is the DBInteractionBase that it inherits

```
Public MustInherit Class DBInteractionBase
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected _connection As SqlConnection

    Public Sub New()

         _connection = New SqlConnection
         _connection.ConnectionString = "some conn string"
            End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub Dispose()
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub


    Protected Overridable Overloads Sub Dispose(ByVal isDisposing As Boolean)
        ' // Check to see if Dispose has already been called.
        If Not _isDisposed Then
            If isDisposing Then
                ' // Dispose managed resources.
                _connection.Dispose()
                _connection = Nothing
            End If
        End If
        _isDisposed = True
    End Sub
```

Now when the code is executing, the Dispose never gets called by the calling web page.  What I am wondering is if the dispose code ever gets executed by the GC?  Another issue I see possibly is that if GetDictConnectionString has an exception, it never rethrows the original sql exception. Would that somehow leave the sql object in memory?   Keep in mind this is a .NET 1.1 application and (GC in .NET 1 is not very efficient)

Also I am wondering what I can monitor on the web server using perfmon to indicate a memory leak.  I am planning on modifying this code and would like an indicator that the issue was fixed.  I see a trend in SqlClient: Current # connection pools - it's growing steadily 1000 each day (It's Current number of pools associated with the process.) so I am wondering if it should go down as the Sessions decrease.  I am looking at (\ASP.NET Apps v1.1.4322(**Total**)\Sessions Active) to see what the server load looks like.

Comment: Why do you declare dictConnection as a new SqlConnction and then reassing it to the existing _connection? I should also point out that you don't really want to dispose of SqlConnections. When you execute Close, they get returned to the connection pool. Once you continue to use the same connection string, they'll be reused automatically.

Comment: I don't know why they declare a new sqlconnection object, but that's on my list to refactor.  I just want to know if that has any implications in the issues we are having. If you don't dispose SqlConnection Object properly does it have possibility to linger in memory?

Comment: SqlConnections will linger by default, but for performance that's generally a good thing and it should only grow the number of pooled objects to a set size.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness, it is incorrect to say that you don't want to call `Dispose()` on a `SqlConnection`. MSDN says that calling `Close()` and `Dispose()` are functionally equivalent in that they both return the connection object to the pool. MSDN highlights the `Using()` pattern which calls `Dispose()` for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx

Comment: Chris, you are correct! My mistake - I think I was trying to get the point across that calling dispose doesn't necessarily free the object due to pooling.

Comment: Does one need to explicitly call Dispose() on the oDictionary object in this scenario to make sure the SqlConnection object is disposed of properly before exiting the Page Load Method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
'new sqlconnection object for another sqlcommand
Dim dictConnection As New SqlConnection
dictConnection = _connection  'At this point the _connection is closed.
```

Is creating two `SqlConnection`s (the `As New SqlConnection` is creating one), and the first would never be disposed. This could certainly be a source of leaking connections.

You're also disposing of the connection `_connection` that you never created (can't see where this is being created). Assuming it's being created 1:1 this shouldn't be a huge problem, but if an exception occurs before your `Try` block, this connection will also not be disposed. If `_connection` is not being created 1:1 for this code, you might end up getting `ObjectDisposedException` if something else tries to use it.